# In redis 2.8, how to modify value and keep untouched the TTL

Tags: redis, timeout, nosql

I have Redis 2.8.19.

In the sequence below I want that the original expiry time of 60 seconds will not be reset when modifying the value of `mykey`.

```
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> SET mykey A EX 60 NX
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> TTL mykey
(integer) 53
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> GETSET mykey B
"A"
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> TTL mykey
(integer) -1
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> GET mykey
"B"
```

After the `GETSET`, I would have expect that `TTL mykey` returns about `40` seconds instead of `-1`.

**Is is possible to modify the value without losing, nor resetting, the timeout?**

Thank you for any hint or solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis' `SET` command clears the key's TTL. There's no Redis command that will keep it as you are trying to do. However, it is possible to use a Lua script that will set and expire the key per your requirement. The script would probably look as follows:

```
local ttl = redis.call('TTL',KEYS[1])
redis.call('SET',KEYS[1],ARGV[1])
redis.call('EXPIRE',KEYS[1],ttl)
return "OK"`
```

`

Comment: thank you. I am using jedis, so I've done a ttl= jedis.ttl(...); jedis.set(key, value, XX, EX, ttl). I'd say is almost atomic :) Nevertheless, an atomic UPDATE key value command would be welcome (if it doesn't modify the TTL) :)

Comment: Doing it w/ Jedis isn't atomic. Executing the above script is. For running Redis Lua with Redis, here's a nice helper: https://github.com/RedisLabs/luascript

Answer (score 2):

There's now an option called `keepttl` that the SET command has. From the docs:

> KEEPTTL -- Retain the time to live associated with the key.

Still isn't supported in GETSET, but, hey, progress!

Answer (score 0):

In case of a simple counter, this is doable by using the INCR/INCRBY and DECR/DECRBY commands. They will increment and decrement a counter respectively and will leave the TTL value untouched.